# AWS Athena: SELECT * not allowed from relation that has no columns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Facing below the error when trying to access some table but some is working properly what can be the reason.

Query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM icbs_cup00901_d LIMIT 1
```

Same Query is working for other tables so I am confuse what can be the reason and mentioned table in query has 8 columns with string data type.

> Error: Your query has the following error(s):
>
> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:8: SELECT * not allowed from relation that has no columns
>
> This query ran against the "bpd_ds_db" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: a462d56e-952b-4a6f-a275-b0c9db0301b0.

I have checked that we have 8 columns in same table with string data type and the exact same query works for some tables so I am confused what's the issue may be

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE icbs_cup00901_d( 
    cux1ac_acct_surr_id string, 
    cux1ap string, 
    cux1cs_cust_surr_id string, 
    cux1ty string, 
    cuxbk string, 
    cuxnot string, 
    cuxrec string, 
    cuxrel string
)

ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' STORED AS 
INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat' 
LOCATION 's3://bpd-datalake/00Raw/datasets/parquet/DWH/ICBS_CUP00901_D' 
TBLPROPERTIES ( 
   'lastUpdateDate'='2021-09-30 03:02:04.780351', 
   'last_modified_by'='hadoop', 
   'last_modified_time'='1632970985', 
   'parquet.compress'='GZIP', 'transient_lastDdlTime'='1632970985'
)
```

Comment: Could it be like the error message says that the table has no columns? Post the table schema. This is not enough information.

Comment: @Theo - I Have checked that we have 8 columns in same table with string data type and the exact same query working for some tables so i am confuse what can be the issue

Comment: "relation" does not necessarily mean table. But without the table schema and the query there's no way to know. Add these to your question.

Comment: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `icbs_cup00901_d`(
  `cux1ac_acct_surr_id` string, 
  `cux1ap` string, 
  `cux1cs_cust_surr_id` string, 
  `cux1ty` string, 
  `cuxbk` string, 
  `cuxnot` string, 
  `cuxrec` string, 
  `cuxrel` string)

Comment: ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://bpd-datalake/00Raw/datasets/parquet/DWH/ICBS_CUP00901_D'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'lastUpdateDate'='2021-09-30 03:02:04.780351', 
  'last_modified_by'='hadoop', 
  'last_modified_time'='1632970985', 
  'parquet.compress'='GZIP', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1632970985')

Comment: @Theo- hey please have a look over the added comments, last 2 comments are the table schema which you have to merge .. apologies, as facing issue in pasting the schema in single note so break in 2 comments

Comment: @Theo- I have shared Query and schema both, query in post and schema in comment

Comment: Just edit the question, your comments are not readable. Also include a query.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue, found out it was because my user did not have sufficient permissions. The error is not very helpful, but I suppose it cannot see the columns, so gives that error.

Resolve it by adding the permissions in AWS Lake Formation. Under Data Lake Permissions, make sure your user has atleast the 'Describe' and 'Select' permissions on the database and the table.

Comment: Thanks to share the information! In my case I am not sure whether it was related to permission or not but yes, in my case issue was in the '*' when I relaced with required column names then it was working properly

Comment: @Harsh Could be not all columns were granted to you so you can't query "*" but selective columns that was granted to you. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone to share the information! In my case I am not sure whether it was related to permission or not but yes, issue was in the '*' when I replaced with required column names then it was working properly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For this issue, you need to grant the select access in the Lake Formation.
Select the role you are using and grant at least the select access,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).